# AWS Codebuild | Docker | Unable to pull customer's container image | a Windows version 10.0.17763-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I created and push the windows container of asp.net mvc project to the docker hub. I want to implement CI/CD in .net project using aws codebuild and aws pipeline service.

When I start the CodeBuiding it gives me below error.

**BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's container image. CannotPullContainerError: a Windows version 10.0.17763-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host**

Comment: As it said, version conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

If you build an Image on Docker for Windows Server 2019, push it to DockerHub/ECR and then tried to use it in CodeBuild, it will not work and throw the error you witnessed.

This is because the underlying host is Windows Server 2016 and the Image is not compatible [1].

CodeBuild team will be adding the support for Server 2019 but there is no ETA.

Ref:

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility#windows-server-2016-host-os-compatibility